# Problems with custom spinner alignment and width

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-spinner

I've created a custom spinner using my own ProjectSpinnerAdapter. I've also got another class which just inflates the layout but hasn't been implemented yet so is still using the standard spinner.

I can't seem to get my custom spinner to align the same way as the standard spinner.

I'm also having problems when the length of the item is wider than the table cell as you can see below. Is there not a way to truncate the options if they are over a certain length ? - This doesn't seem like its the correct way to fix this but I can't directly set the width of the widget as this is controlled via the table layout.*

**Fixed, See update*

### Screenshots

[image: screenshot]
[image: screenshot 2]

The standard spinner aligns perfectly with the Button it sits next to (they are both contained within the same TableRow)

### layout

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:stretchColumns="1" >

<TableRow>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/selectButton"
        android:text="@string/show" />

    <Spinner android:id="@+id/projectSpinner" />
</TableRow>
```

### spinner_list_item.xml (Uses maxLength)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/title_text_view"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:maxLength="15"
          android:gravity="center"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

### Update

The issue was the layout of the spinner item, in my custom layout spinner_list_item.xml I'd specified a layout all I needed was the textview

**spinner_list_item.xml (Uses maxLength)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/title_text_view"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:maxLength="15" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I may ask, why did you choose the TableLayout? I think the same could be achieved with a `RelativeLayout` and `layout_toRightOf` `layout_below`, etc. Or a `LinearLayout` with a `weightSum` and `gravity` each child having a `layout_weight`.

I'm not going to give you a solution that changes your entire layout though ;), but I tested this and this seems to work for me.

```
<TableRow>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/selectButton"
        android:maxLength="10"
        android:text="sdadadasdfffffffffffffffffffffffff"/>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/projectSpinner"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:lines="1"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true" />
</TableRow>
```

Hopefully this works and it's a better way than setting a fixed string length

**edit**

I'm not sure why you're populating the spinner the way you are, but you can try:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/title_text_view"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_centerInParent="true"
          android:maxLength="15"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

`android:gravity` is wrong too, needs to be `android:layout_gravity` (but that's LinearLayout only

**Last edit :D**

try using the default layouts

```
view = vi.inflate(android.R.layout.spinner_list_item, null);
```

then

```
((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text1)).setText(title);
```

Comment: Thats a pretty tidy solution for the width problem - thanks. Any ideas about the alignment issues ?

Comment: Ok so I specified the 'maxLength' attribute for the 'TextView' in the spinner_item.xml and left the full length in spinner_dropdown_item.xml and that's resolved the width problem. +1

Comment: nothing jumps out at me, can you post the xml of `R.layout.spinner_list_item` . Perhaps your parent TableLayout should use width:fill_parent and height:wrap_content?

Comment: changed the Table Layout, but it still doesn't line up correctly.

Comment: can you please show this layout `view = vi.inflate(R.layout.spinner_list_item, null);` ?

Comment: I've included it in the original post. its got a single textview in it, which I'm now setting the maxLength for.

Comment: Sorry i'd labelled it it incorrectly, I've corrected the label to spinner_list_item.

Comment: I thought that I'm getting the item from the spinner position in the list, I've just encapsulated it locally as a Project so I can call the project get methods. I'll need to call other methods from the project so I wanted to keep it locally rather than chain lots of methods to access it each time.

Comment: @Luke I added an alternative solution to your custom adapter since it looks like you're just using it for the most basic of reasons? Alternatively I think, alternatively, you could keep the custom adapter and use the default android views instead of the custom TextViews (like android.R.layout...). Looks like your application is simple enough where you don't necessarily need a custom adapter

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8674/discussion-between-luke-and-bbedward)